# I want to install GUI applications on Bash on Windows

Tags: bash

I wanted to install some GUI applications on Bash on Windows but I got `GTK_BACKEND doesn't match available displays`. I searched for this error, but none of them actually solved it. I've tried `pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY` and `export DISPLAY=:0`. Finally I found that it's related to X server. Can I run X on Bash, or it needs more than Bash to run?

Comment: You need the x-window server plus some window manager. Some people did it: http://linux.softpedia.com/blog/you-can-now-run-ubuntu-linux-with-the-unity-desktop-on-top-of-windows-10-506159.shtml , but it's still experimntal and buggy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just reading this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/261575/how-to-run-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-windows-10s-bash-shell/) yesterday.

1. Install an X Server - [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) is a good and free
2. Install the Program - for example Vim `sudo apt-get install vim-gtk`
3. Set Your Display Environment Variable - `export DISPLAY=:0`
4. Launch an Application - `gvim`

You can combine the steps 3 and 4 if you want.  `DISPLAY=:0 gvim`

A commenter added:

> If you don't want to run the export DISPLAY=:0 each time you open a bash shell, open .bashrc in a text editor. Examples of ways to open a text editor with .bashrc:
>
> nano ~/.bashrc gedit ~/.bashrc
>
> Then, add export DISPLAY=:0 to the end of the file. The .bashrc file is like the autorun file in Microsoft Windows. It gets executed every time a new Bash window is opened.