# Onboard Keyboard to work with WIndows 10 subsystem

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, on-screen-keyboard

I have a device that runs linux in the background. I am working on the code on my windows 10 machine in Qt. Qt takes up A LOT of space and time, so much so that I do not dare dual boot my laptop to install Qt there to test.

We want to use [onboard](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/onboard.1.html) for our onscreen keyboard because of its customization. I have been running the ubuntu subsystem for windows 10 and have installed onboard. However, when I try to run it, I get:

```
hermes@DESKTOP-A66D2I7:~$ onboard &
[1] 2204
hermes@DESKTOP-A66D2I7:~$ Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(onboard:2204): Gdk-WARNING **: 10:33:05.682: cannot open display:
```

I have visited this site: https://askubuntu.com/questions/768508/cant-launch-graphical-apps-from-terminal-after-updating-to-15-10, where I tried the commands in the two answers but to no avail. I do not have a file that is named .Xauthority.

Does anybody have a solution, or must I uninstall Qt and return to using ubuntu as my daily OS? Thanks.

Comment: Use a Xserver in Windows (e.g. Xming, VcxSrv etc.) And add `export DISPLAY=:0` in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to install GUI applications on Bash on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1099981/i-want-to-install-gui-applications-on-bash-on-windows)